# Explanation for the creation/existence of a secondary physical space that experiences time differently

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, space, time, spacetime-dimensions

In this world I'm building, I need it to be possible to have enclosed spaces/worlds connected to the main one. Ideally the main world would closely resemble ours, with the same laws of energy/physics/time/space etc, although differences will have to be allowed if that's the only way to accommodate the existence of these spaces. Time needs to progress differently in these spaces in relation to the main world, with 1 hour in the main world = to 24 hours in the secondary ones. Gravity should feel the same. If the size of these secondary worlds is significant, they would be at most 1 000 000 square feet.

As for the connection between the worlds, I feel with enough research and exaggeration I can use portals/wormholes. I haven't figured it out yet, but there's enough information on the theory behind them that I should be able to. If you have ideas or summaries that you'd like to add it would still be appreciated.

Right now the closest I'm getting is some kind of enclosed system out in space, in distant rotation / accelerating to the point that time will be experienced differently in the two places. I would prefer some kind of stationary or inter-dimensional (?) space if at all theoretically possible. It would also be acceptable if the secondary world was scaled down and enclosed somewhere on the primary one, though I'm not sure what other changes a scale change would indicate.

I'm sorry for asking, but I haven't been able to find any theoretical or pseudo-scientific explanations for what I'm suggesting. If this idea sounds familiar to you and I'm just not using the right terms to search for it, I would appreciate if you shared those instead.

Browsing this website has been hugely helpful to me in building this world so far, so even if this is a dead end I appreciate just having a place to ask the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track.

Assuming I'm understanding what you are saying correctly, the best way to explain the time difference would be equal to the rotational speed of each planet. Your main planet's day lasts 24 hours, and the outer planets' days lasts 1 hour.

That would mean the outer planets' rotational speed should be equal to *24 multiplied by main planet speed*.

P.S, for your portals, I believe there is inspiration to be found in the book series of Hyperion... or perhaps a sort of 100-200 foot portal arc on a planet seems exciting. I don't watch/read much sci-fi material, but it sounds like an under-used portal type.

**EDIT**:

I apologize for the late reply. I can't seem to find any real concepts on this, or think of a good one for that matter.

With that said, I would say your best bet is to make a fabricated answer seem logical. You could simply say alien technologies, if your using aliens in your story. Or perhaps something like gravitational time; that is, gravity has an effect on time in some way.

Or when portals are open, time leaks through these portals. The amount of time could be dependent on the larger planet's gravitational pull.

So, the larger(main) planet essentially steals time from the outer planets.

I think the last explanation is logical, except for explaining how time is affected by gravity.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll keep reading up on time dilution.

Comment: Oh, I see then! Very different. So what you are saying is: Time on main planet is normal(or the standard time), but time on the other planets moves faster. I'll think about this more. How flexible can you be with creativity in this? Should it be based on other concepts, or would you be okay with a fabricated explanation?

Comment: I would prefer if it was based on real concepts, but I think fabrication will be necessary. And yes, exactly, it would go faster in the secondary places. The idea is to have a people travel between the two places, and for them, time will feel to be progressing at the same rate in both worlds. So if they were to travel from the real world to the secondary one at 1pm, and spend what feels like a full 24 hours in this secondary place, when they return to the main world only an hour has passed and it is 2pm.

Comment: @shakycheese, thanks for replying. I've edited my answer to reflect this. Hopefully this helps!